# Check IF is a "single product page" and Check the "role" for a Redirect

Tags: pages, woocommerce-offtopic, redirect, user-roles, single

After much research on the net, I have not found a solution that works.

Do you know how can I do that on woocommerce :

I try that for the moment :

```
function cm_redirect_users_by_role() {

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

    if ( is_products_page() && is_single() ){
        if ( $role_name === 'customer' ) {
            wp_redirect( 'https://www.mysite.fr/shop/' );
        } // if
        else {
            wp_redirect( 'https://www.mysite.fr/' );
        } //
    }
} // cm_redirect_users_by_role
add_action( 'admin_init', 'cm_redirect_users_by_role' );
```

But that not work :/ when I'm on a single product page, I'm not redirect.

Answer (score 16):

Here is the result that works, I put in the condition : `is_product()` to check if is a single product page.
And I changed in the `add_action()` : **admin_init** by **wp**

```
function cm_redirect_users_by_role() {

    $current_user   = wp_get_current_user();
    $role_name      = $current_user->roles[0];

    if ( is_product() ){
        if ( $role_name !== 'customer' && $role_name !== 'shop_manager' && $role_name !== 'dc_vendor') {
            wp_redirect( 'https://www.mysite.fr/' );
        } // if
    }
} // cm_redirect_users_by_role
add_action( 'wp', 'cm_redirect_users_by_role' );
```

Comment: Hi, Please consider using the same account for posting, commenting, answering, etc.